# Adding/Replacing Header to First Page only for existing Word Document with OpenXML 2

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am working on a solution with OpenXML SDK 2.0 to add or replace the Document Header part only for the First Page of the Document. I have added `HeaderReference` type as `HeaderFooterValues.First`. But it is not adding the Header. I have tried without that and it is adding the Header to every page. The code I used is below here.

```
static void ChangeHeader(String documentPath)
{
      // Replace header in target document with header of source document.
      using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentPath, true))
      {
           // Get the main document part
           MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = document.MainDocumentPart;

           // Delete the existing header and footer parts
           mainDocumentPart.DeleteParts(mainDocumentPart.HeaderParts);

          // Create a new header and footer part
          HeaderPart headerPart = mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();

          // Get Id of the headerPart and footer parts
          string headerPartId = mainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(headerPart);

          GenerateHeaderPartContent(headerPart);

          // Get SectionProperties and Replace HeaderReference and FooterRefernce with new Id
          IEnumerable<SectionProperties> sections = mainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>();

          foreach (var section in sections)
          {
            // Delete existing references to headers and footers
            section.RemoveAllChildren<HeaderReference>();

            // Create the new header and footer reference node
            section.AppendChild<HeaderReference>(new HeaderReference() { Id = headerPartId, Type = HeaderFooterValues.First });
           }
        }
}
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have figured out what is the issue.

Even though I have added the HeaderReference Type as First, it is not activated unless you add the Title Page property to Section Properties. So Updated code will be like this.

```
static void ChangeHeader(String documentPath)
{
      // Replace header in target document with header of source document.
      using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentPath, true))
      {
           // Get the main document part
           MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = document.MainDocumentPart;

           // Delete the existing header parts
           mainDocumentPart.DeleteParts(mainDocumentPart.HeaderParts);

          // Create a new header part
          HeaderPart headerPart = mainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>();

          // Get Id of the headerPart
          string headerPartId = mainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(headerPart);

          GenerateHeaderPartContent(headerPart);

          // Get SectionProperties and Replace HeaderReference with new Id
          IEnumerable<SectionProperties> sections = mainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<SectionProperties>();

          foreach (var section in sections)
          {
            // Delete existing references to headers
            section.RemoveAllChildren<HeaderReference>();

            //Adding Title Page property
            section.PrependChild<TitlePage>(new TitlePage());

            // Create the new header reference node
            section.AppendChild<HeaderReference>(new HeaderReference() { Id = headerPartId, Type = HeaderFooterValues.First });
          }
       }
}
```